# Infinispan: Case Insensitive querying via HotRod

Tags: java, case-insensitive, infinispan, querying

Is there a possibility to use non case sensitive querying via hotrod with Infinispan 8.1.2?
For example something like that:

```
RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager = ...;
RemoteCache<Integer, Book> remoteCache = remoteCacheManager.getCache();

Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setTitle("Hibernate");
remoteCache.put(1, book1);

Book book2 = new Book();
book2.setTile("Infinispan");
remoteCache.put(2, book2);

QueryFactory qf = Search.getQueryFactory(remoteCache);
Query query = qf.from(Book.class)
  .having("title").in("infinispan").toBuilder()
  .build();

List<Book> list = query.list(); // Voila! We have our book back from the cache!
```

Comment: Answered [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/952588?et=watches.email.thread#952588)